# Does any set admit a total order?

Tags: order-theory, cardinals

Is it true that any set $P$ can be endowed with a total order $"\leq" \subseteq P\times P$?

Comment: The ambiguous "any".  Is there any set that admits a total order?  Certainly.  I can show you such a set.  But you probably meant "Is it the case that any set at all, no matter which one, admits a total order?".  The ambiguity vanishes if you simply use the word "every", thus: "Does every set admit a total order?". ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact any set admits a well ordering. This fact is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice.

Of course the empty set is excluded.

For finite sets, axiom of choice is not needed.  For infinite sets, the idea is, roughly,
pick $x_1\in S$ where $S$ is an inifinte set, then pick $x_2\in S\setminus\{x_1\}$, and
$x_3\in S\setminus\{x_1,x_2\}$ and so on.

Comment: Do you know if (or to what extent) choice is required?

Comment: using ordinary (“naive”) set theory, well-ordering is equivalent to Choice. Indeed, well-ordering looks stronger, since any subset of a well-ordered set has a least element, and that gives you your choice.

Comment: The empty set admits a total order.

Comment: @GEdgar Hmm.  I imagine what you're saying is that the empty set can be equipped with the empty relation, which is vacuously a total order.  Is that the idea?

Comment: @Lubin: Naive set theory? If it's the one that admits Russel's paradox any two statements would be equivalent.. I guess you mean equivalent over ZF (which is rather not naive).

Comment: In the naive set theory I’m talking about, there’s an Aussonderungsaxiom all right, but no set of all sets. So Russell’s paradox does not arise. I guess I’m thinking of my own primitive notion of ZF.

Comment: In the manner you presented your answer all we can have is to extract a countable set from $S$. What if $S$ is uncountable?

Comment: That's a good point.  The method of transfinite induction is used for uncountable sets.